# remove view from right to left with animations

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewanimation

I adding view when btw is clicked from left to right and want to remove this view from right to left.

Below is my code while adding view from left to right

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];

leftMenu = (LeftMenuViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                             instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"menuController"];



leftMenu.view.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320-50, self.view.frame.size.height);


[self addChildViewController:leftMenu];
[self.view addSubview:leftMenu.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

    leftMenu.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320-50, self.view.frame.size.height);
    hoverView.hidden = NO;


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [leftMenu didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}];
```

For removing this view from right to left what i have tried is:

```
 self.view.frame = CGRectMake(320-50, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);



} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [self removeFromParentViewController];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

}];
```

I want to remove view from right to left .Any help how to proceed further?

Comment: And what is the problem with your second snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must move your subview out of frame of superview, so set x-coordinate of your subview to negative value of it's own width. This will cause your view move from right to left out of view.

```
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [self removeFromParentViewController];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    }];
```

Comment: @ Doro above code changed to swift 3.0 but not working..Any help?

Comment: Better do: [self.view removeFromSuperview]; [self removeFromParentViewController]; because I get crash if removeFromSuperview is after removeFromParentViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it like this:

```
    CGRect napkinBottomFrame = Yourview.frame;
 napkinBottomFrame.origin.x = 0;
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{ Yourview.frame = napkinBottomFrame; } completion:^(BOOL finished){/*done*/}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 and 4 version:

```
leftMenu.didMove(toParentViewController: nil)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
    animations: {
        self.leftMenu.view.frame = CGRect(x: -self.view.frame.width, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    },
    completion: { finished in
        self.leftMenu.view.removeFromSuperview()                            
        self.leftMenu.removeFromParentViewController()
})
```

P.S. leftMenu should be class variable (property)